# Valor de un JSON o NSDictionary a integer

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Estoy haciendo pruebas en un webservice al coger el valor de un `JSON` que devuelve ( es un entero ) me tira un error.

Para coger el valor lo hago con:

`[[respuesta valueForKey:@"code"] integerValue]`

El error que sales es un:

> [__NSSingleObjectArrayI integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000016830

Si hago un `NSLog` de `[respuesta valueForKey:@"code"]` como `NSString` me sale el numero pero separado entre paréntesis y espacios, algo asi: `(         1          )`. El 1 seria el valor que quiero pasar a entero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de hacer varias pruebas lo he resuelto, dejo la solución por si alguien le pasa lo mismo alguna vez.

La web me devolvía el JSON entre corchete [ ] y dentro las llaves { } por lo que esto objective-C lo ve como un array con indice 0 donde para acceder bien tenia que hacerlo de esta manera: [[[respuesta objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"code"] integerValue]

La manera como lo probaba al principio servia solo si el código estaba entre llaves { }

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tratar de hacer Parse de los objetos con CocoaPods

https://cocoapods.org/pods/JSON

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación